# How to perform a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test in R after creating clusters?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I used the hierarchical clustering approach on my dataset and created 3 clusters, which I added as a variable to my dataset.
I would like to perform the Wilcoxon Mann Whitney test on the three clusters (clusterID) and their respective variables.

This is the dataset

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEfFt.png)

Comment: a reproducible example is always nice. also, some [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) to the statistic you're looking for (especially since it's one that goes under many names and you're using a less common name for it) and a description of what research you did before asking.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

Source 1: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03409

```
# Clustered Wilcox test
clusWilcox.test(x ~ grp + cluster(cid), dat.cl, method = "rgl")
```

Source 2: https://www.statmethods.net/stats/nonparametric.html

```
# independent 2-group Mann-Whitney U Test
wilcox.test(y~A)
# where y is numeric and A is A binary factor

# independent 2-group Mann-Whitney U Test
wilcox.test(y,x) # where y and x are numeric 

# dependent 2-group Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test
wilcox.test(y1,y2,paired=TRUE) # where y1 and y2 are numeric
```

Next time please include a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example.